# Issue with loop involving if statements and functions

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

The Desired outcomes of this program are as follows:

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: 1
Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: 1
Enter radius of sphere: 5.5
Volume of sphere is 696.91

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: 1
Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: 2
Enter radius of sphere: 5.5
Surface area of sphere is 380.133

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: 2
Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: 1
Enter radius of cylinder: 5.5
Enter height of cylinder: 4.2
Volume of cylinder is 399.139

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: 2
Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: 2
Enter radius of cylinder: 5.5
Enter height of cylinder: 4.2
Surface area of cylinder is 335.208

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: 3
Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: 1
Enter radius of cone: 5.5
Enter height of cone: 4.2
Volume of cone is 133.046

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: 3
Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: 2
Enter radius of cone: 5.5
Enter height of cone: 4.2
Surface area of cone is 214.607

Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: q

Good bye!

I think you can tell where I'm heading with this...Why can't i get my loop to work properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double sphere_volume(double radius);
double sphere_surface_area(double radius);
double cylinder_volume(double radius, double height);
double cylinder_surface_area(double radius, double height);
double cone_volume(double radius, double height);
double cone_surface_area(double radius, double height);

int main()
{
double entHeight;
double entRadius;
char shapeCall;
char compCall;

cout << "Select a Shape (1) sphere (2) cylinder (3) cone (q) quit: ";
cin >> shapeCall;
cout << "Select a Computation (1) volume (2) surface area: ";
cin >> compCall;


    if ( shapeCall == 1 && compCall == 1)
    {
            cout << "Enter Radius: ";
            cin >> entRadius;
            cout << sphere_volume (entRadius) << endl; 

    }
    if ( shapeCall == 1 && compCall == 2)

    {
            cout << "Enter Radius: ";
            cin >> entRadius;
            cout << sphere_surface_area (entRadius) << endl;
    }
    if ( shapeCall == 2 && compCall == 1)
    {
            cout << "Enter Radius: ";
            cin >> entRadius;
            cout << "Enter Height: ";
            cin >> entHeight;
            cout << cylinder_volume (entRadius, entHeight) << endl;
    }
    if (shapeCall == 2 && compCall == 2)
    {
            cout << "Enter Radius: ";
            cin >> entRadius;
            cout << "Enter Height: ";
            cin >> entHeight;
            cout << cylinder_surface_area (entRadius, entHeight) << endl;
    }
    if (shapeCall == 3  && compCall == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter Radius: ";
        cin >> entRadius;
        cout << "Enter Height: ";
        cin >> entHeight;
        cout << cone_volume (entRadius, entHeight) << endl;
    }
    if (shapeCall == 3 && compCall == 2)
    { 
        cout << "Enter Radius: ";
        cin >> entRadius;
        cout << "Enter Height: ";
        cin >> entHeight;
        cout << cone_surface_area (entRadius, entHeight) << endl;
    }
system ("pause");
return 0;
}


double sphere_Volume(double radius) 
  { 
   return 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14159 * pow( radius, 3 ); 
  }
double cylinder_volume(double radius, double height)
  { 
  return 3.14159 * pow(radius, 2) * height;
  }
double cone_volume(double radius, double height)
  {
  return 1.0 / 3.0 * 3.14159 * pow(radius, 2) * height;
  }
double sphere_surface_area(double radius)
  {
  return 4.0 * 3.14159 * pow(radius, 2);
  }
double cylinder_surface_area(double radius, double height)
  {
  return (2.0 * 3.14159 * pow(radius, 2)) + (2.0 * 3.14159 * radius * height);
  }
double cone_surface_area(double radius, double height)
  {
  return (3.14159 * pow(radius, 2)) + (3.14159 * radius * sqrt(pow(radius, 2) +  pow(height, 2)));
  }
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work properly?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems.  You declare `sphere_volume`:

```
double sphere_volume(double radius);
```

but you define `sphere_Volume`:

```
double sphere_Volume(double radius) 
{ 
    return 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14159 * pow( radius, 3 ); 
}
```

Since you use `sphere_volume` in `main`, you should probably change the definition to `sphere_volume`.

The other problem is that you don't actually have a loop.  Your `main` function will run once, but then it will hit `return 0;` and the program will terminate.

One way to add a loop would be to enclose the code after starting with your first `cout` and ending before `system("pause")` with `while(shapeCall != 'q')`.